# Error en el diseño de la Etiqueta Fieldset html, en asp.net mvc

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc, fieldset

Estoy tratando de usar las etiquetas  y , para dar un estilo mas atractivo al formulario, estoy usando asp.net mvc, pero al correr el formulario el diseño no se visualiza como se vería normalmente, se pierde el estilo y el cuadro del fieldset no se visualiza.

Agregué las etiquetas como normalmente se utilizan y como mvc tiene clases de estilos predeterminadas, le agregue una clase de estilos propia al fieldset para ver si así se podría visualizar el diseño y aun asi no se visualiza correctamente.